# How do I get hibernation or suspension working on a Acer Aspire 5742G?

Tags: 12.10, hibernate

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Acer Aspire 5742G recently but I can't neither put it to hibernation nor suspend it. If I hibernate it then when I press the power to wake it up, it doesn't show anything on the display and I have to force power it down (by pressing the power for a few seconds), and press the power again. Even sometimes the same thing happens when I shut down the laptop.

I tried TuxOnIce, without success.

As far as I know it's not a bug in 12.10. My internal wireless card is not working properly and I am using a USB wireless card. Do you think it might be the reason? Any one has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: how much **RAM** do you have? Do you have the 8GB model or a lesser one? Most of the time it is usually RAM that causes that.

Comment: It's 4GB. Is it because of that?

Comment: It might be you may have many running system processes. Do you have MYSQL, APACHE or any DB or server installed?

Comment: No, I am not running any of them on the machine. It's a clean install, and I have not installed any software on that yet.

Comment: well that is queer you have enough memory let me ask around then

Comment: Thanks for helping. It is really annoying not to be able to hibernate.

Comment: OK
I guess it was because of my graphic card driver. I reinstalled it and now it seems to be fine.
btw my graphic card is Geforce 420m

Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply. Please answer your own question to close it. I am glad you figured it out.